# Chef knife job start error

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo, knife

I am getting an error while running knife job start. knife node status shows up my node as available. I am working with private chef here.

```
➜  org-y-chef-repo  knife job start 'chef-client' 'node-y'
ERROR: The data in your request was invalid
Response: invalid key supplied
```

Can someone please see my logs . Thanks

```
➜  org-y-chef-repo  knife job start 'chef-client' 'node-y' -VV
INFO: Using configuration from /Users/ssi/code/chef/hosted_chef_workspace/org-y-chef-repo/.chef/knife.rb
DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::JSONInput#handle_request
DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::JSONToModelOutput#handle_request
DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::CookieManager#handle_request
DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::Decompressor#handle_request
DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::Authenticator#handle_request
DEBUG: Signing the request as chef-admin
DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::RemoteRequestID#handle_request
DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::ValidateContentLength#handle_request
DEBUG: Initiating POST to https://ec2-52-11-189-186.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/organizations/org-y/pushy/jobs
DEBUG: ---- HTTP Request Header Data: ----
DEBUG: Content-Type: application/json
DEBUG: Accept: application/json
DEBUG: Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3
DEBUG: X-OPS-SIGN: algorithm=sha1;version=1.0;
DEBUG: X-OPS-USERID: chef-admin
DEBUG: X-OPS-TIMESTAMP: 2015-09-17T22:17:12Z
DEBUG: X-OPS-CONTENT-HASH: r1iu92tKg+ICzk4A9c2mGaVtt1I=
DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-1: C0koxcunocZTWzc9whDU8kr5TzH2dgluzHXkT3qMeCITq1XgtvpmXjbikaLG
DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-2: pavDHNMCWbNwCzdoXVOewRzMJ585PLoCG5c4wbaImv8v33A2ejGeOyYPTrbJ
DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-3: llpcQS+JRI74R/E4rUONh1dfCcDXbJlKrkCvu/Rh34cv4z9xleVM/CrRd7G3
DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-4: 2rQab6X+6TmSD4WDY9BRqC+PpCLl94pk5Dts1cvoDqJOXg221Jn1rJuJnDiq
DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-5: X8lefonUS9Xd2XaNNkI4d6qVSLxkvLlQKK2lYKisVnbkIB+2nZQlxk2pk1uS
DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-6: u8IvMA4svTqa+JTQ/TesdofuaUd1wJ7qdDET2xc6DQ==
DEBUG: HOST: ec2-52-11-189-186.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:443
DEBUG: X-Ops-Server-API-Version: 1
DEBUG: X-REMOTE-REQUEST-ID: 0510040a-a9da-4b6f-83a5-63c541849b19
DEBUG: Content-Length: 87
DEBUG: ---- End HTTP Request Header Data ----
DEBUG: ---- HTTP Status and Header Data: ----
DEBUG: HTTP 1.1 400 Bad Request
DEBUG: server: openresty/1.7.10.1
DEBUG: date: Thu, 17 Sep 2015 22:17:12 GMT
DEBUG: content-length: 32
DEBUG: connection: close
DEBUG: ---- End HTTP Status/Header Data ----
DEBUG: ---- HTTP Response Body ----
DEBUG: {"error":"invalid key supplied"}
DEBUG: ---- End HTTP Response Body -----
DEBUG: ---- HTTP Request Body ----
DEBUG: {"command":"chef-client","nodes":["node-y"],"capture_output":false,"quorum":1,"env":{}}
DEBUG: ---- End HTTP Request Body ----
DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::ValidateContentLength#handle_response
DEBUG: Content-Length validated correctly.
DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::RemoteRequestID#handle_response
DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::Authenticator#handle_response
DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::Decompressor#handle_response
DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::CookieManager#handle_response
DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::JSONToModelOutput#handle_response
DEBUG: Expected JSON response, but got content-type ''
DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::JSONInput#handle_response
INFO: HTTP Request Returned 400 Bad Request: error
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:119:in `error!': 400 "Bad Request" (Net::HTTPServerException)
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/http.rb:145:in `request'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/http.rb:126:in `post'
    from /Users/ssi/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/knife-push-0.9.0/lib/chef/knife/job_helpers.rb:96:in `run_helper'
    from /Users/ssi/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/knife-push-0.9.0/lib/chef/knife/job_start.rb:106:in `run'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife.rb:425:in `block in run_with_pretty_exceptions'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:39:in `with_server_connectivity'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife.rb:424:in `run_with_pretty_exceptions'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife.rb:215:in `run'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/knife.rb:142:in `run'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/bin/knife:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/chefdk/bin/knife:55:in `load'
    from /opt/chefdk/bin/knife:55:in `<main>'
➜  org-y-chef-repo
```

I can see that my node is available :

```
➜  org-y-chef-repo  knife node status
node-y  available
```

Comment: As far as I know there's no `--as-user` option in `knife job start`, it's added to the json sent and the push job server find it as a bad key in the JSON object, thus returning this error.

Comment: I've removed the --as-user option and I still get an error. Are you using Chef server 11?

Comment: I'm basing my comment of the latest doc, if you're on chef server 11 with push jobs, it means you're on a enterprise chef, so with a Chef Inc. support...

Comment: According to the url used you're on private chef 11 or chef 12, there's of chef-dk with a ruby version 2.1.0 sounds like your workstation is using chef 12 too, so the advice is still valid. 'still get an error' is unclear, I can't guess what the error is now... And I'm pretty sure it changed

Comment: It hasn't changed. I get the exact same error. I am using private Chef 12.

Comment: The request body has to be different without the --as-user...  i can not see logs not interested the question, please [edit] with latest state... (and don't prune too much, sometimes the culprit is not the error on itself)

Comment: @Tensibai. Thank you for looking into this. I've edited the logs to show the latest logs.

Answer (score 0):

please use node name without quotes

knife job start 'chef-client' node-y